# Error to Install Gazebo on Ubuntu

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

rushabh@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                                                                                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed InRelease                                                                                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                                                                                              
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]                                                                            
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed Release.gpg [933 B]                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg                                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                                                                                  
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]                                                                              
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed Release [49.6 kB]                                                                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release                                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted amd64 Packages                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_GB                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_GB    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_GB      
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise InRelease                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en         
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7,957 B]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [159 kB]                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release                                                                     
Hit http://packages.osrfoundation.org precise InRelease                                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                               
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://packages.osrfoundation.org precise/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise Release                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://packages.ros.org precise/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1,970 B]                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en                   
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]           
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [13.3 kB]                                 
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [1,937 B]                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/multiverse Translation-en                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/restricted Translation-en                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/universe Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_GB                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en_GB            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign http://packages.ros.org precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign http://packages.osrfoundation.org precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign http://packages.osrfoundation.org precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 285 kB in 3s (86.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
rushabh@ubuntu:~$ . /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh
bash: /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh: No such file or directory
rushabh@ubuntu:~$ echo "source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
rushabh@ubuntu:~$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh: No such file or directory
rushabh@ubuntu:~$ . /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh
bash: /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh: No such file or directory
rushabh@ubuntu:~$ gazebo
gazebo: command not found
rushabh@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gazebo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gazebo : Depends: libfreeimage3 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libprotobuf-dev but it is not installable
Depends: freeglut3 but it is not installable
Depends: libcurl4-openssl-dev but it is not installable
Depends: libogre-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-urdfdom but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libboost-thread1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-signals1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-system1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-filesystem1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-program-options1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-regex1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1 but it is not installable
Depends: robot-player but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libcegui-mk2-0.7.5 but it is not installable
Depends: libavformat53 but it is not installable
Depends: libavcodec53 but it is not installable
Depends: libswscale2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1194/error-to-install-gazebo-on-ubuntu/) by [rdd0101](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/194/rdd0101/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See [question 1190](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1190/installation-errors-on-ubuntu-1210/)

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0